# Using NSInteger for type id in NSDictionary objectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsinteger

I'm trying to insert a key value of `indexPath.row` in a `dictionary`. When I do just `indexPath` (without `.row`) it works fine. But when I add the `.row`, it gives me an error saying:

```
Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger (aka 'long') to paramater of type 'id'
```

Here is my code:

```
[self.myDict objectForKey:indexPath.row];
```

Then when I add integerValue at the end of it, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `NSInteger` is just a typedef (alias) for a `long` or `int` depending on the device. If you command click on `NSInteger` you can see it defined as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `NSDictionary` can only deal with object, a simple way to use your `NSInteger` as a key is to wrap it in a `NSNumber` object:

```
[self.myDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
```

Also, a better way to use NSNumber is to use literals, for example:

```
[self.myDict objectForKey:@(indexPath.row)];
```

More information about literals [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: You could also use the nice objective-c literals syntax to wrap the value: `..valueForKey:@(indexPath.row)`

Comment: I took away my upvote due to the changes made to the original answer. Do not use `numberWithInt:` for an `NSInteger`. It's best to use the `@( )` syntax anyway. And do not use `valueForKey:` to lookup a value from a dictionary. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a specific reason to use key-value coding.

Comment: I edited my post back. I'm completely agree with you about the literals, but I was thinking it can be more confusing if the reader don't know this syntax. Finally, I let both syntax in order to be explicit. Also, thanks for the `valueForKey`, it was a mistake, I fix it.

Comment: OK, now you mention using `objectForKey:` twice. Why?

Comment: Almost there. Change `numberWithInt:` to `numberWithInteger:` and it'll be perfect. That was one the points in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I met this question , but the condition is not so similar. I was tring to pass a `NSInteger` in the block but the parameter is the `id` type. But the complier tell me that **Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC**, then I noticed that `id` type is defined by Objective - C, BUT NSInteger is just a BASE TYPE which means can't be conversed to a Objective-C type parameter.

I think there are two ways for you to resolve this problem.

1. Don't Pass a NSInteger type as a parameter to a Objective-C type .(In method and block and all other where can pass a paramter)
2. NSInteger can be conversed to the `NSNumber` type which is a Objective - C type, then you can use the value of the NSInteger variable.(Using the `@()` *syntactic sugar* is welcome for a coder)